# Tried using apply function inside tapply for aggregate means of a particular attribute

Tags: r

tried using apply function along with `tapply`, but an error shows up stating that argument `FUN` missing.

I tried using apply function separately. When I passed it inside `tapply`, there was this error. I am using the Swedish motor insurance data set and I would there is a column named Zone which has a value from 1-7. All the rows have one out of the 7 values. I would like to compute the means for each Zone by grouping them.

```
tapply(apply(ins[,c(5,6,7)]),Zone, mean)
```

expected the means for each Zone

```
  Insured           Claims       Payments
1 1036.17175       73.568254    338518.95
2 1231.48184       67.625397    319921.52
```

resulted with an error.

Comment: could you add `dput(ins)` ?

Comment: This is a typo. You are not providing a function (FUN argument) to `apply`.

Comment: I think you have to put the tapply inside the apply. Something like apply(ins[5:7], 2, tapply, ins$Zone, mean)

Comment: Why not just use the dplyr `group_by` and `summarize` functions?